# Gulp for registering S3 as Lambda function's event source

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gulp, aws-lambda

I'm using `node-aws-lambda` Gulp plugin to upload Lambda function which's zipped by `gulp-zip`. This is the example of `lambda_config.js` in this plugin's github page:

```
module.exports = {
  accessKeyId: <access key id>,  // optional
  secretAccessKey: <secret access key>,  // optional
  profile: <shared credentials profile name>, // optional for loading AWS credientail from custom profile
  region: 'us-east-1',
  handler: 'index.handler',
  role: <role arn>,
  functionName: <function name>,
  timeout: 10,
  memorySize: 128,
  runtime: 'nodejs', // default: 'nodejs'
  eventSource: {
    EventSourceArn: <event source such as kinesis ARN>,
    BatchSize: 200,
    StartingPosition: "TRIM_HORIZON"
  }
}
```

I want my Lambda function'll be triggered by uploading a jpeg file to a S3 bucket. Although i set this S3's ARN to `EventSourceArn` but i didn't find where i could set the suffix for the valid file (`.jpg`, `.jpeg` etc..) and an error's displayed when running `gulp` command.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the bucket, go to "properties", then "events". Here you can select a suffix to the file that would trigger the event. If you have several possible suffixes, I guess you can only add several rules

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i want to use `gulp` for setting this config because i have several lambda functions and many s3 buckets :(

Comment: O I see. However, on the lambda side you only specify the ARN of the event. The events have to be created on the bucket side, and that's where the filters you are looking for are configured. Are you also creating the buckets using gulp? Can you interact programmatically with these buckets? If you explain why you are trying to do so maybe we could find another solution

Comment: No, i'm creating the buckets manually. There're many settings in 'Add event source' screen <in tab Event sources in Lambda function side>, so i think `gulp` can take it in lambda side. I'll try to write code to add events from bucket side later. Thank you for your comment !!